# c# convert bytes to double with a "higher" precision

Tags: c#

I always convert bytes to double with `System.BitConverter.ToDouble()` like this:

```
double value = BitConverter.ToDouble(flt, 0);//flt is an array of bytes.
```

But when I try to convert "8**A** 7F DA 0C 41 6D A6 40"(Little Endian),it become `2870.62705118949`.

Indeed, `2870.62705118949` is "8**E** 7F DA 0C 41 6D A6 40".

But what I want is `2870.6270511894881565`.How can I get the accurate value using C#?

Answer (score 5):

When working with *exact string representation*, use "R" formatting:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx

> "R" or "r" Round-trip Result: A string that can round-trip to an
>   identical number.

In your case

```
  Byte[] data = { 0x8A, 0x7F, 0xDA, 0x0C, 0x41, 0x6D, 0xA6, 0x40 };

  Double value = BitConverter.ToDouble(data, 0);

  Console.Write(value.ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); // "R" formatting
```

And as you can see, the actual value is not `2870.62705118949`  but `2870.6270511894882`; just compare the values:

```
  2870.6270511894882     Actual
  2870.6270511894881565  You want to have
  2870.62705118949       Proposed by changing 8A into 8E
```

and see that "8**A** 7F DA 0C 41 6D A6 40" is, in fact, a better choice (*more accurate*)